# How to pass URLError / HTMLError to csv file using Requests?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

newbie here.

In my code below, I am scraping a list of URLs for certain HTML data which is then written to a csv file, each row containing the data for each URL. The code also checks if a URL has a URLError or HTMLError, in which case it prints that to the console. However, instead of printing "URL Error" or "HTML Error" to the console, I'd like to pass that to the csv file, in the second column labelled "Error Report" (where "ErrorReport" is in the "row =" line). This way I can view the csv file to see which URLs resulted in an error.

```
import requests
import bs4
import lxml
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
import csv


def getTitle(soup):
    return soup.find('title').text.strip()

urlList = ["https://stackoverflow.com"]

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')  as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Title', Error Report])
    
    for url in urlList:
        try:
            html = urlopen(url)
        except HTTPError:
            print("HTML Error")
        except URLError:
            print("URL Error")
        else:
            soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
            row = [ErrorReport, getTitle(soup)]
            print(row)

            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd slightly restructure your script: First gather all data into a structure such as list, then create a DataFrame from this list and then you can save the dataframe as a CSV file:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError

def getTitle(soup):
    return soup.find('title').text.strip()

urlList = ["https://stackoverflow.com", "http://nonexistentwebpage.example"]

all_data = []
for url in urlList:
    try:
        r = urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.read(), 'html.parser')
        all_data.append([url, getTitle(soup), None])
    except HTTPError:
        all_data.append([url, None, 'HTTP Error'])
    except URLError:
        all_data.append([url, None, 'URL Error'])


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['URL', 'Title', 'Error Report'])
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                                 URL                                                            Title Error Report
0          https://stackoverflow.com  Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers         None
1  http://nonexistentwebpage.example                                                             None    URL Error
```

and saves `data.csv`:

```
URL,Title,Error Report
https://stackoverflow.com,"Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers",
http://nonexistentwebpage.example,,URL Error
```

[image]